# Create a batch file to run a specific exe which has a few other parameters

Tags: batch-file, pdf, cmd

Here's the thing: There's an exe file to stamp on PDF through command line.
the file is from this website:
[pdfmachine-command-line-tools](https://pdfmachine.com/genp/pdfmachine-command-line-tools.html)

and this is the link to download the exe file:
[pdfMachineStamp](https://pdfmachine.com/pdfMachineStamp.exe)

**PREVIOSULY:**
I paste both the downlaoded 'pdfMachineStamp.exe' from the website, and also paste my 'prueba.pdf' (PDF file to stamp) here, manually:
C:\PDF

**HOW THE EXE WORKS?:**
Then I go to run MANUALLY on the System Symbol:
C:\PDF>pdfmachinestamp.exe /f prueba.pdf /t "This is the Stamp" /pos center /size 15 /rot 45 /color black /opacity 1

and it runs perfect!
My 'prueba.pdf' ends with a stamp in the center of the page rotated 45 degrees saying "This is the Stamnp".

**THE PROBLEM:**
NOW, I want to create a batch file to do that with a single click... but I'm new in this, and I'm stuck...
I dont' know if i have to edit the bat file with START,RUN, CD, or... ????

Then I tried

```
start /d "C:\PDF\pdfMachineStamp.exe" /f prueba.pdf /t "PRUEBA REAL" /pos center /SIZE 25 /rot 45 /color black /opacity 1
PAUSE
```

and it won't work.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: `start` considers the first set of quotes that it encounters to be the title of the window. Try `start "" /d "C:\PDF\pdfMachineStamp.exe" /f prueba.pdf /t "PRUEBA REAL" /pos center /SIZE 25 /rot 45 /color black /opacity 1` to give the command some throwaway quotes.

Comment: hello @SomethingDark thanks for the comment!

Comment: for some reason, the it's retrieving this message (translated from spanish) 'modifier not valid: "/f".' What else could I try after that?

Comment: Make sure you've got quotes in the right places and that the command in the script matches the command that works when you type it manually, I suppose.

Comment: start "" /d "C:\PDF\pdfMachineStamp.exe" /f prueba.pdf /t "PRUEBA REAL" /pos center /SIZE 25 /rot 45 /color black /opacity 1
PAUSE

Comment: above the command copied from my bat file... not working... :(

Comment: `/D` is the working directory, not a filename! Please open a Command Prompt window, type `start /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the output. `@Start "" /D "C:\PDF" "C:\PDF\pdfMachineStamp.exe" /f "prueba.pdf" /t "This is the Stamp" /pos center /size 15 /rot 45 /color black /opacity 1` Howevwer, I really think you should get rid of the `start` command, `@CD /D "C:\PDF" 2> NUL && "pdfMachineStamp.exe" /f "prueba.pdf" /t "This is the Stamp" /pos center /size 15 /rot 45 /color black /opacity 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I honestly didn't have idea how to make it right, but after playing a little bit and some other research in this matter i found a solution that did exactly what i want easily.

This is the script:

```
start "" "C:\PDF\pdfMachineStamp.exe" /f "C:\PDF\prueba.pdf" /t ""PRUEBA_REAL"" /pos center /size 30 /rot 45 /color green /opacity 1
```

I decided to use `start ""` to begin the command line, and had to use the double quotes to highlight the names of both files (the exe and the pdf). Also, I used the full path for both. for the Stamp text, I had to use double-double quotes and avoid spaces (replaced by _). and that's it.

Thanks everybody!
I hope this is useful for somebody in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `start` or `call` for your purposes.

Instead you simply put the command you want there.

If you plan to keep the batch fine in the same folder as the `prueba.pdf` and `pdfmachinestamp.exe` than you can use this shorthand `%~dp0` to specify the path to `C:\PDF\`, this is because `%0` is the '0th' argument of the script,, and used to hold the full path and file name of the current script (and the current label within the script if within one.) and `~dp` selects just the `drive` (`d`) and `path` (`p`); to the script from the `%0` variable.

Therefore this should do the needful

```
@Echo off
"%~dppdfMachineStamp.exe" /f "%~dpprueba.pdf" /t "PRUEBA REAL" /pos center /SIZE 25 /rot 45 /color black /opacity 1
PAUSE
```

You can double click this cmd script or a shortcut to the script and it should run as expected.

However, make sure you have named it `scriptname.cmd` if you use `notepad` change the type to `any` instead of before saving and remove `.txt` from the end.

Also make sure "hide file extensions for known file types" is turned off in explorer (which is on my default) as windows will hide the ".Txt" at the end of the file if present, so you can be sure it is named correctly.